# RxJava2 Ignore element if it currently exists in a stream

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I have a case when I need to drop/ignore element if it is **currently** presented in a reactive stream. For example:

```
fun ignoreDuplicatesExample() {

    val publishSubject: PublishSubject<Long> = PublishSubject.create()
    publishSubject.observeOn(Schedulers.single()).distinct().subscribe({
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        println("onNext: $it")
    }, {
        error("$it")
    })

    publishSubject.onNext(1)
    publishSubject.onNext(2)
    publishSubject.onNext(3)

    publishSubject.onNext(1) // should be ignored
    publishSubject.onNext(2) // should be ignored
    publishSubject.onNext(3) // should be ignored

    Thread.sleep(10_000)
    publishSubject.onNext(1) // by this time it should be already consumed, so it need to be allowed to emit it again
    publishSubject.onNext(4)

    Thread.sleep(10_000)
    println("exit")
}
```

Output:

```
onNext: 1
onNext: 2
onNext: 3
onNext: 4
exit
```

But I expected to see:

```
onNext: 1
onNext: 2
onNext: 3
onNext: 1
onNext: 4
exit
```

So, anybody know how to achieve it using RxJava2?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it straightforwardly because upper stream chain shouldn't know down streams, if it is "consume"d or not. (Imagine if there are several subscribers.)
If you want to do, you need to interact with variable that is in outside of stream.